# onDrawerClosed and onDrawerOpened not being called

Tags: java, android, navigation-drawer

I am playing with the DrawerListener , and unfortunately the official documentation is not quite detailed, not to say there aren't any examples  given.

All I want to test is showing a Toast message when the Drawer closes, but its just not happening, its not being called at all, any ideas  ? Below the code

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements DrawerLayout.DrawerListener {

  DrawerLayout.DrawerListener mele;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    final DrawerLayout olia=(DrawerLayout)findViewById(R.id.container);

    ListView meka=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);

    String [] karo={"meka","deka","beka"};

    ArrayAdapter<String> mera=new ArrayAdapter<String>     ( this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,karo);  

    meka.setAdapter(mera);

     olia.setDrawerListener(mele);      


    meka.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener () {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub


              olia.closeDrawers();
        }



    });





}

@Override
public void onDrawerClosed(View arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub


    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "OK Opened", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Log.d("meke", "CLOSED  DRAWER" );
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try `olia.setDrawerListener(this)`

Comment: well, the Context is not the problem. Your MainActivity was also your DrawerListener. So the code that shows the Toast was not in 'mele' but in your MainActivity. 'mele' is not initialized here and is still null

Comment: thanks for the info, do you have some links with either examples or more information on the subject , also on onDrawerSLide etc

Comment: http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html
This tutorial on the Android Developer site should get you started properly

Comment: this is for beginners, I am not a beginner, even though the trivial question here

Answer (score 1):

Since the method `setDrawerListener(listener)` is deprecated, you should use `addDrawerListener(listener)`.

Answer (score 0):

i have created a sample app for your issue Please check the solution , Now its working fine.

```
    public class YourActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements  DrawerLayout.DrawerListener {

    DrawerLayout drawer;
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_dash_board);
 final DrawerLayout olia=(DrawerLayout)findViewById(R.id.container);
        olia.setDrawerListener(this);
    }//onCreate()

    @Override
    public void onDrawerOpened(View arg0) {
      //write your code
    }

    @Override
    public void onDrawerClosed(View arg0) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onDrawerSlide(View arg0, float arg1) {
        //write your code
    }

    @Override
    public void onDrawerStateChanged(int arg0) {
        //write your code
    }
}//class
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that `setDrawerListener(DrawerLayout.DrawerListener)` is deprecated.

Use `addDrawerListener(DrawerLayout.DrawerListener)` instead.